# Content encoding error after enabling cache, aggregation and compression

Tags: 7, caching

Yesterday I turned on caching, aggregation of css and js files and turned on compress cached pages. Then I logged out and closed my browser (FF). After a couple of minutes I openend my browser again, typed in the url of my website and got this error in FF: Content encoding error.

I tried opening my site in FF, Chrome and IE. None of them work.

I read some similar threads here and tried:
- setting display_errors=Off in php.ini
- disabling gzip of files in .htaccess
- Changing "Header append" to "Header set" in .htaccess

Nothing seems to work.

What I would like to do now is manually disable caching, aggregation and compression in the database, but I don't know which tables these settings reside in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this lines to your settings.php file.

```
$conf = array(
'cache' => '0',
'preprocess_css' => '0',
'preprocess_js' => '0',
'block_cache' => '0',
'page_compression' => '0',
);
```

or with Drush

// To turn on JS Aggregation

```
drush vset preprocess_js 1 --yes
```

// To disable JS Aggregation

```
drush vset preprocess_js 0 --yes
```

// To clear cache of JS and CSS only

```
drush cc css+js
```

// To enable CSS Aggregation

```
drush vset preprocess_css 1 --yes
```

// To disable CSS Aggregation

```
drush vset preprocess_css 0 --yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It works, I can access my site again. Now I still need to figure out what exactly causes the "Content encoding error".

Comment: @Smos Drupal sends these files gzipped to save bandwidth. But your servers messes with http headers. Some hosting companies thinks it's good idea, dunno why :|

Comment: @Smos  Using Drupal output compression along with Apache mod_deflate can result in double compression.  I don't recall getting a "Content encoding error" with this.  When this happens, I have always seen a page full of junk characters.

Comment: @MPD http://home.pl used to mess my headers even without own compression. Content was compressed, once, but browser didn't get an info about that at all. So this can be screwed up at least 2 ways. But I bet there are more.

Comment: @Mołot  Odd, never seen that one.  Sounds line a bad proxy not honoring Vary: Accept-Encoding

Comment: @MPD there are so many ways to make a problems to your users ;) Fun fact - while Drupal can't be sent from home.pl with any compression, their own main site is gzipped all right. It was a reason of some puns in Polish Drupal related forums, as home.pl is one of the big players in hosting business here.